# What does documents_columns paramter in Sparse2Corpus do?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I searched gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus documentation but I do not find what does True/False value for documents_columns do.
Ex: gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(input, documents_columns=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It represents your documents as columns `documents_columns=True` or rows `documents_columns=False`. From the [source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/matutils.py#L537)

```
if documents_columns:
    self.dense = dense.T
else:
    self.dense = dense
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw this description but what does "T" mean? Transpose matrix? Why and when we should use the transpose matrix?

Comment: yes, "T" is to transpose the array, `Dense2Corpus` expects a `numpy.ndarray`. It will depend on how are your documents represented, are they stacked as vertical arrays (represented as columns) or are they stacked as horizontal arrays (represented as rows).